# newsfeed icon showing tiny box counter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

```
<head>

<style>
    .divTable {
        display: table;
        float: right;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: #0082CA;
    }

    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }

    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }

    .menuLink, .icon {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 10px 0px;
    }

    .menuLink {
        display: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

        .menuLink a {
            font-size: large;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

    .divTableRow:hover {
        background-color: #005C8F;
    }

    .icon {
        width: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

        .icon img {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

    .userProfile {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('.menuLink, .icon')
            .mouseover(function () {

                $(".menuLink").stop(true, false).fadeIn(280);
                $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
                    width: "300px",
                    opacity: "1",
                    "padding-left": "10px"
                });
            })

            .mouseleave(function () {

                $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
                    width: "0px",
                    opacity: "0",
                    "padding-left": "0px"

                });       
            });
    });

</script>
```

```
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="menuLink"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">news feeds</a>
                </div>

                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="img/signout.png" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I like to create a counter on top of an icon which is similar to Facebook where you have a tiny red box to show how many friend requests but I do not know how should I begin. Am I right to said this can be done by tooltip?

I have a menu containing a newsfeed icon and I am using C# and HTML language. So I like to know how can I create the tiny box displaying the number of news system have.

Thank you,

Comment: [favico.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/) will do what you want, I think.

Comment: Inspect similar ones in your browser dev tools...will see it is usually done with simple html and css

Comment: @AnonCoward Thank you so much but do you have any sample code on how to use it? i planning to use it on one of the .png picture in my menu.

Comment: @AnonCoward I have pasted my code above, may i know how should i begin?

Comment: @AnonCoward is there any different between Tinycon ?